# Excel doesn't show all data points

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have an Line graph in Excel 2010 displaying data on 7 areas every friday through the end of the year.  The graph currently shows the data through the end of October but will not display data beyond that point.  How can I get the chart to show the remaining weeks?  Below is image of test data set and lay out.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on any of the graphs; in the formula bar you will see the 'Formula' that creates this graph, for example `=SERIES(Sheet1!$A$3;Sheet1!$B$2:$N$2;Sheet1!$B$3:$N$3;1)`

1. The first parameter is the *Title* of each graph;
2. the second parameter is the X-range
3. the third parameter is the Y-range
4. the fourth parameter is the sequential count.

Your problem is the second parameter; but not just anyone: typically, all your graphs share this parameter, and you can only edit it in #1. Here is what you need to do:

1. use cursor down or up to step through all graphs, until you see graph *1* in the formula bar (not necessarily *your* first graph; and it doesn't really matter which one of yours it is)
2. in this formula, edit the X-range to include the remaining columns, for example, change `$B2:$N2` to `$B2:$W2`.
3. edit the Y-range to include the remaining columns *too*, for example, change `$B3:$N3` to `$B3:$W3`. Press `<RET>`. Your first graph should now show all data points.
4. repeat this for all other graphs (X might be automatically ok, but Y needs to be adjusted.

Note that there are more fancy ways to do so, by using the Excel-supplied dialogs and controls, but they are very different in each version, and some of them behave counter-intuitive. Generally, Excel tries to be clever, and sometimes that helps, and sometimes not. I always use the 'manual' way as described, and once you understood the four parameters, it is straight forward, and you can create any kind of special graphs with it.

Comment: Thanks! That's a pity I cannot upvote your answer 10 times :)